# Recently downloaded iOS 17 onto my iPhone 13 Pro Max and have a unknown icon

Tags: ios, icon

Recently upgraded to iOS 17 on my iPhone 13 promax I have no idea what this icon is and can find no info on it. Does anybody have any idea what the world this is?[image: Or]

Answer (score 1):

This is the new icon for Voice Control being active.

- In iOS 16, it is a microphone vertically on a stand, on a blue bakground.
- In iOS 17, it is a waveform on a blue background.

Toggle Voice Control or learn more in Settings → Accessibility → Voice Control.